# character shows up as 'y' instead of a space '

Tags: matlab, caesar-cipher

In matlab i'm coding a Ceaser Cipher, but the space shows up as a 'y' character.
How can I replace that with a space

```
    case 4
        disp('Breaking Ceaser Cipher')
        cs = menu('Please Enter your Choice','Encryption','Decryption');
        if cs==1
           c = input('Enter the message: ','s');
           sh = str2double(input('Enter shift: ','s'));
           c=upper(c);
           lc=length(c);
           for i=1:lc
               p(i)=int16(c(i))-65+sh;
           end
           p=mod(p,26)+97;
           p=char(p);
           disp( p)
        end
    end
```

output example:

```
Breaking Ceaser Cipher

Enter the message: 

my name is jeff

Enter shift: 
5

rdysfrjynxyojkk
```

Here we see that the encryption is correct, but the space is being replaced by 'y'. It does not replace the character 'y' when used as an input, the space bar somehow comes out as a 'y'.
I'v also tried using `p2 = regexprep(c, 'y', ' ')` in order to replace the 'y' string with space.Also looked into isspace function.  No luck

Comment: Can you show us your attempt with `isspace`? I can't see why it would not work

Comment: i added c= c(find(~isspace(c)));  right under 'sh ' variable. When using the same plaintext and shift number, I get the output: rdsfrjnxojkk

Comment: Right. so you more or less have it. You have selected all `c` that are not a space, that works well. You just forgot to add the spaces back later! Note that you don't need find, logical indexes work: `c= c(~isspace(c));`

Comment: I guess my issue is, how and where to add the space back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are halfway there:

```
spaces=isspace(c)
% make array of spaces
out=blanks(size(c));
% get array without spaces
c=c(~spaces);
% do stuff to c, without spaces. 
p=mod(p,26)+97;
p=char(p);
% Fill p in corresponding locations
out(~spaces)=p;
```